# Gluon Connect DataProvider.retrieveList results in IllegalStateException

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

Following code produces an `IllegalStateException` - not on FX application Thread - .

```
private void populateListView(){
    GluonObservableList<MyClass> items = DataProvider.retrieveList(restClient.createListDataReader(MyClass.class));
    listview.setItems(items);
}
```

I guess the reason for this is that the code which adds the elements from the `Iterator` to the `GluonObservableList` is not wrapped in `Platform.runLater()`, despite to the other calls in `retrieveList()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating a UI element (such as listview) must be done from the FX Application Thread. 
If populateListView() is called from a background thread, the observableList updates in the background causing the listview to try to update from the background.

Setting the observableList to the listview using Platform.runLater occurs on the FX Thread but the observableList still updates in the background after it is loaded to the listview.

```
new Thread(()->{
    GluonObservableList<MyClass> items = DataProvider.retrieveList(restClient.createListDataReader(MyClass.class));
    //Option 1 
    //listview.setItems(items);
    //Option 2
    //Platform.runLater(()->listview.setItems(items));
    //Option 3
    //items.initializedProperty().addListener((obv,ov,nv)->{
    //    listview.setItems(items);
    //});
    //Option 4
    items.stateProperty().addListener((obvs,ovs,nvs)->{
        if (nvs.equals(ConnectState.SUCCEEDED)) {
            listview.setItems(items);
        }else if(nvs.equals(ConnectState.FAILED)){
            MobileApplication.getInstance().showMessage("Rest API request failed");
        }
    });
}).start();
```

Option 1 and Option 2 update the listview before data is loaded to the observableList. Option 1 and 2 throw multiple exceptions (and option 1 is just ugly).

Both option 3 and option 4 trigger the listview update after the observableList has been loaded and are handled on the FX Application Thread. 

Alternatively, you can wrap any call to populateListView() in Platform.runLater

Comment: I guess my question should have been more precise... Actually I'm using Option 3, which I think is the way `GluonObservableList` is supposed to be used. I was just wondering why the `Iterator` in `DataProvider.retrieveList` is not wrapped in a `Platform.runLater()`, which makes now perfect sense  to me, e.g. when you consider a situation where you use it in a `Thread` that doesn't update the UI.

Comment: Just adding a quick comment to this, it does make perfect sense to directly set the items on a ListView, as in Option 1. Because the GluonObservableList is an ObservableList, any items that are added to it, will automatically be reflected in the ListView control, just like when you are using a regular ObservableList. The call to DataProvider.retrieveList must be executed on the FX app thread as well. Gluon Connect already does the actual retrieval of the list in it's own background thread, so there is no reason for a developer to call this from outside the FX app thread.

Comment: In the example I specifically called DataProvider and populated the listview from a background thread for option 1.which produced an error.. This would work if on the FX Thread. Option 2 still produces errors as DataProvider is still called from background.  DataProvider works great in that there is no need to go to a background thread to request data.